# Error al registrar datos en mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy teniendo problemas al registrar datos en una tabla con `php`. Al darle al botón de registrar, no me da ningún error, pero no se me registra en la tabla, os pongo los archivos. No veo el fallo. Indicar que, `nom_dep` y `usuario`, son claves foráneas con otras tablas, no se si ahí viene el problema.

PHP-

```
<?php session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['identificador'])){
        require 'frontend/crearIncidencia-vista.php';
    }else{
        header ('location: login.php');
    }
    
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $nom_dep = $_POST['nom_dep'];
        $categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
        $cliente = $_POST['cliente'];
        $cod = "INC" . 000000;
        $subcategoria = $_POST['subcategoria'];
        $entorno = $_POST['entorno'];
        $estado = $_POST['estado'];
        $resumen = $_POST['resumen'];
        $texto = $_POST['texto'];

        $error = '';

        if (empty($usuario) or empty($nom_dep) or empty($categoria) or empty($subcategoria) or empty($entorno) or empty ($estado) or empty ($resumen) or empty ($texto) or empty($cliente) ){
            $error .= '<i>Por favor rellena todos los campos</i>';
        }else{
            try{
                $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=service_ticketing', 'root', '');
            }catch(PDOException $prueba_error){
                echo "Error: " . $prueba_error->getMessage();
            }
        }


        if ($error == ''){
            
            $statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO incidencia (cod, usuario, nom_dep, categoria, subcategoria, entorno, estado, resumen, texto, cliente ) VALUES (null, :usuario, :nom_dep, :categoria, :subcategoria, :entorno, :estado, :resumen, :texto, :cliente');
            $statement->execute(array(
                
                ':usuario' => $usuario,
                ':nom_dep' => $nom_dep,
                ':categoria' => $categoria,
                ':subcategoria' => $subcategoria,
                ':entorno' => $entorno,
                ':estado'=> $estado,
                ':resumen'=> $resumen,
                ':texto' => $texto,
                ':cliente'=> $cliente
                
            ));
            $cod= $conexion->lastInsertId();
            $incidencia ="INC".$cod;
            $statement2 = $conexion->prepare('UPDATE incidencia SET incidencia = :incidencia WHERE cod = :cod');
            $statement2 ->bindParam(":incidencia",$incidencia, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
            $statement2 ->bindParam(":cod",$cod, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
            $statement2->execute();
               echo var_dump($statement);
            $error .= '<i style="color: green;">Incidencia registrada correctamente</i>';
        }
    }
```

HTML

```
<form action="crear-Incidencia.php" method="post" class="form">
  <div class="form-group text-left" >
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Usuario</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" name="usuario" placeholder="" value="<?php echo  $dato['usuario']; ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group text-left">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Nombre del departamento</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="nom_dep">
    <option>Elige una opcion</option>
      <option>Unix</option>
      <option>Wintel</option>
      <option>CAU</option>
      <option>Monitorizacion</option>
      
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group text-left" >
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Cliente</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="" name="cliente">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Categoria</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="categoria">
    <option>Elige una opción</option>
      <option>Maquina</option>
      <option>Proceso</option>
      <option>Usuario</option>
      <option>Ratio Error</option>
      
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group text-left">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Subcategoria</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="subcategoria">
    <option>Elige una opción</option>
      <option>Sin conexion</option>
      <option>Instancia Caida</option>
      <option>Problema Usuario</option>
      <option>Problema Monitorizacion</option>
      
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group text-left">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Entorno</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="entorno">
    <option>Elige una opción</option>
      <option>Desarrollo</option>
      <option>Pre-produccion</option>
      <option>Produccion</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group text-left">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Estado</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="estado">
    <option>Elige una opción</option>
      <option>Nueva incidencia</option>
      <option disabled>En proceso</option>
      <option disabled>Solucionado</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group text-left" >
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Resumen</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="" name="resumen">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group text-left">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="texto"></textarea>
  </div>

  <?php if(!empty($error)): ?>
            <div class="mensaje">
                <?php echo $error; ?>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Registrar</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: ¿La columna `incidencia` puede tener valor nulo? Porque no la estás incluyendo al registrar.

Comment: Si, puede tener un valor nulo

Comment: Falta rigor en tu código. Hay al menos 2 posibles errores no controlados: 1. El INSERT podría tener un error de sintaxis y podría causar la violación de alguna restricción; 2. El UPDATE lo mismo dicho en (1) ... Tu código no debería ignorar olímpicamente esos dos posibles errores. Empieza por controlarlos y dinos qué ocurre. Te aconsejo que seas todo lo pesimista que puedas programando, que pienses en TODO lo que puede salir mal y que programes para controlar eso que salga mal.

Comment: Solo hay error en el punto 1, en el insert, le faltaba un ). El update está bien.

Comment: Ya, pero yo me refiero a otra cosa: se trata de escribir un código que prevea y controle todos los errores, también los de posibles violaciones de restricciones como clave duplicada, integridad referencial, etc. Si ignoras eso el código puede fallar y romperse sin que haya de tu parte una respuesta a esa situación. No sé si me entiendes.

Comment: Te entiendo perfectamente, si.

Answer (score 0):

Después de ejecutar tus transacciones tienes que consignar los datos con un `commit` prueba usando:

```
$conexion->commit();
```

Te comparto la documentación para que puedas consultarlo [Aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.commit.php)

Comment: En la documentación hay una nota referente a MySQL.